# How I can get the color value from string with rgb color?

Tags: javascript

I have an element with some `background-color`. When I use `element.style.backgroundColor` then I get the string like `rgb(221, 110, 43)`. How I can get, for example, **blue** value of the color (i.e. 43)?

Comment: Did you tried to parse the string ?

Comment: Yes, it is one of the ways, but I think that this isn't a "beatiful" way:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regex:

```js
function getRGB(str){
  var match = str.match(/rgba?\((\d{1,3}), ?(\d{1,3}), ?(\d{1,3})\)?(?:, ?(\d(?:\.\d?))\))?/);
  return match ? {
    red: match[1],
    green: match[2],
    blue: match[3],
    alpha: match[4]
  } : {};
}

console.log(getRGB("rgb(211, 211, 211)").blue);
console.log(getRGB("rgba(211, 0, 211, 0.5)"));
```

Comment: You included a case for alpha but didn't return it

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex to parse the RGB Color values.

```js
var color = 'rgb(24, 45, 12)';
var parsedColor = color.match(/^rgb\s*\(\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*\)$/i);
console.log([parsedColor[1],parsedColor[2],parsedColor[3]]);
```